# What is #{ 'column_name' } in Magento?

Tags: magento-enterprise

I am trying to get attribute set in dropdown in my custom module.
I have override **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Array_Abstract** class in my custom module.
There is one line, in the code which says

```
$value = (string) '#{' . $columnName . '}';
```

If I `echo $value` it displays me `10` as value but when I try to compare it in `if` condition

```
if($value == '10')
```

It returns false. 
I have tried using temp variable to store value for `$value` but without success. Please guide how to get value for `$value` in `if` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#{ }` is a [PrototypeJS template expression](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Template/). Without knowing exactly your case, it is hard to say for sure, but I'm wondering if you did this `echo $value` within the Javascript Template() rendering function? If that is the case, `#{ $columnName }` would have been evaluated to `10`.

Since you are working in PHP though, where the PrototypeJS template expression hasn't been evaluated, what about accommodating for the expression statement? Would something like this work in your case?

```
if (strpos($value, '10') !== false) {
    // ...
}
```

Or even:

```
$colName = ltrim($value, '#{');
$colName = rtrim($value, '}');

if (strpos($colName, '10') !== false) {
    // ...
}
```

This, however, leaves me wondering if it would be possible to simply use the `$columnName` variable?

Comment: @basspayer7, value for `$columnName` variable is `attribute_set`, it is a string variable but when used as `$value = (string) '#{' . $columnName . '}';` it shows '10'.

Comment: Yes, it sounds to me like PrototypeJS is evaluating `#{attribute_set}` to 10 in your case. So based on that, you may need to either load the attribute sets with your ResourceModel to determine how many there are or do the work on the front end - in JS.